# Perl regex matching alternative file names

Tags: regex, perl

#### Example:

I used to use regex to get extension from the file name:

```
my $name = "file.zip";
my ($fname, $fext) = $name =~ /(.*)\.(.*)/;

# file
# zip
```

Now, I need to make sure that it also properly catches `.tar.gz` files, in case name includes it, otherwise falls back to example above. I did the following:

```
my $name = "file.tar.gz";
my ($fname, $fext) = $name =~ /(.*)\.(tar\.gz$)|(.*)\.(.*)/;

# file
# tar.gz
```

#### Problem:

The problem is that now it only works for `file.tar.gz` and doesn't fall back to catching regular files, like `file.zip`, and returns empty, in the second case.

How do I do this in one regex, so it successfully works for `file.tar.gz` and `file.zip`. What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(.*?)\.(tar\.gz|[^.]*)$/
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\.` - a dot
- `(tar\.gz|[^.]*)` - Group 2: `tar.gz` or any 0+ chars other than a dot
- `$` - end of line.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DotO8R/1).

Alternatively, you might also use your original pattern but wrap it with a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

```
/(?|(.*)\.(tar\.gz)|(.*)\.(.*))$/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DotO8R/2). It will assign the same IDs to the corresponding capturing groups inside the branch reset group. Since `(.*)\.(tar\.gz)` will be tried first, if there is a string ending with `.tar.gz`, the first alternation part (`(.*)\.(tar\.gz)`) will match, else, the second one (`(.*)\.(.*)`) will consume the string.

Comment: Indeed it works. I was missing _branch reset group_ alternations, I think. Thank you very much.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev I found a simpler way without a branch reset. I will add that one, too, if you wish

Comment: This is great. Thank you! 

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -e '$name= "file.zip";($fname,$fext)=$name =~ /(.*)\.(tar\.gz|zip)$/ ;print "$fname.$fext"'
file.zip
```

the number of captured group, ie. 4, is greater than that of assigned variable `($fname,$fext)=` , ie. 2 
only the first 2 group is assigned